# Can I pick a lock on a shop "closed for inventory"?

Tags: nethack

In nethack I encountered a shop "closed for inventory".

I know it won't open on its own. I know I can use a credit card to open it, but I haven't seen any in this game.

Question: can I pick the lock on the doors? Or will it make the shopkeeper angry?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can open the door using lock picks, credit cards, skeleton keys or the knock spell without angering the shopkeeper.

Basically any way to open the door that does not destroy it (like e.g. kicking it in or smashing it with a pick-axe) is allowed.

You're also allowed to teleport or phase into the shop if you have that ability. When teleporting or phasing out of the shop, make sure you pay first or the shopkeeper will call the Keystone Kops.

Comment: Be aware that all other ways to open a door _will_ cause the shopkeeper to charge you for the door.

Answer (score 1):

If you're routinely kicking down doors, shops "closed for inventory" might be a problem. You can carry an axe around instead of kicking -- applying it never chops down a shop door, and therefore never angers the shopkeeper.